# How to store src base64 image in server (folder storage)?

Tags: laravel, image, file, base64, storage

I have a form contains img tag in the src attribute I have a base 64 image, I want to save this image in the public storage folder.

the script below works fine except that it saves a png image but when I preview I see nothing !!!

js +ajax :

```
        $('#form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            formData.append('imgsrc',$('#thumbnail_pic').attr('src')),
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
                url: "{{ route('file.upload') }}",
                data: formData,
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('uploaded');
                }
            });
    });
```

controller :

```
    $image = $request->input('imgsrc');
    $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $imageName = 'test.png';
    $success= Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

Comment: As I got from your question that the problem is not about saving as it's already saving, the saved file is not correct. First check that the form has multi-part in encryption parameter and then make sure before saving the file that the input is file

Comment: the form already has the multi-part in encryption parameters, for the input type file, I don't have it in the form, I created this image from screenshot and save it in img

Comment: if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $image)) {
    $data = substr($image, strpos($image, ',') + 1);
    $imageName = 'test.png';
    $success= Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($data));
}
it might help

Comment: I don't have data:image, i have data:application/octet-stream;base64,....

Comment: then that's why you have this issue, it means your line $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
 doesn't work. it will not affect the string. try:
str_replace('data:application/octet-stream;base64,', '', $image);